# subtract between two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
name   group   val1  val2  
John    A       3     2     
Cici    B       4     3     
Ian     C       2     2     
Zhang   D       2     1
Zhang   E       1     2
Ian     F       1     2
John    B       2     1
Ian     B       1     2
```

I did a pivot table and it now looks like this using this piece of code

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['val_1, val_2], index=['name', 'group']).reset_index()
df

name   group   val1  val2  
John    A       3     2     
John    B       2     1     
Ian     C       2     2     
Ian     F       1     2
Ian     B       1     2
Zhang   D       2     1
Zhang   E       1     2
Cici    B       4     3
```

After the pivot table, I need to calculate 1) groupby name 2) calculate the delta between groups. Take John as an example
The output should be:

```
John    A-B       1     1    
Ian     C-F       1     0
        F-B       0     0
        B-C       1     0  (the delta is -1, but we only do absolute value)
```

How to move forward from my pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Getting each combination to subtract (a-b, a-c, b-c) won't be directly possible with a simple `groupby` function. I suggest that you pivot your data and use a custom function to calculate each combination of possible differences:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def combo_subtraction(df, level=0):
    unique_groups = df.columns.levels[level]
    combos = itertools.combinations(unique_groups, 2)
    
    pieces = {}
    for g1, g2 in combos:
        name = "{}-{}".format(g1, g2)
        pieces[name] = df.xs(g1, level=level, axis=1) - df.xs(g2, level=level, axis=1)
    return pd.concat(pieces)

out = (df.pivot(index="name", columns="group") # convert data to wide format
       .pipe(combo_subtraction, level=1)       # apply our combination subtraction
       .dropna()                               # clean up the result
       .swaplevel()
       .sort_index())

print(out)
           val1  val2
name
Ian   A-B   0.0   0.0
      A-C  -1.0   0.0
      B-C  -1.0   0.0
John  A-B   1.0   1.0
Zhang A-B   1.0  -1.0
```

The `combo_subtraction` function simply iterates over all possible combinations of 2 of "A", "B", and "C" and performs the subtraction operation. It then sticks the results of these combinations back together forming our result.